# Asp.net on Apache setup questions

Tags: c#, asp.net, apache, iis

We have an already existing project on IIS and we want to move to Apache (windows) with mod_aspdotnet. What things could not work? If we use 3rd party DLLs? Will office components work fine (export to Excel, Word, etc). If you have any experience on this type of migration, I'd like your inputs! Also, is there another alternative to mod_aspdotnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used this setup on Windows (Apache/mod_aspdotnet).

I have used mod_mono to run ASP.NET (MVC, WebForms, and custom) apps on Apache/Linux though.  Under that scenario, the code is offloaded to the CLR to be run and so third-party components work fine.  I have sites that import/export Excel, Word, PDF, etc. with no problems.

I would expect that mod_aspdotnet works similarly to mod_mono.

I realize this is not really a direct answer to your question but I thought you might find it valuable.  Also, you have alternatives in case you want to jump even further and host a project on Linux sometime.

**EDIT:** A quick Google (sorry Bing) confirms that it works much like mod_mono but there is a pretty big gotcha.  **It looks like maybe mod_aspdotnet only works with older versions of .NET** (like 1.1).

http://mod-aspdotnet.sourceforge.net/

**EDIT AGAIN:** It seems as though [at least one person made it work with ASP.NET 2.0](http://weblogs.asp.net/israelio/archive/2005/09/11/424852.aspx) which means it worked with the CLR version 2.  Even .NET 3.5 runs on version 2 of the CLR so it may still be an option I suppose.

Comment: Since it's the only answer I got, I'm going to accept it! Thanks for the input. I've read that it should only delegate the requests to the .net framework, so there should not be any problems (in theory).

Comment: @tink01 - Thanks.  Sorry I could not help more.  I agree that the real work is being done by the CLR.  The fact that the sourceforge site said explicitly that it was 1.1 only gave me pause.  Good luck and maybe report back here if it all works well.